# Must doctors and other medical practicioners give treatments based on science?

Tags: canada, health, british-columbia

I went to see a counsellor at my university and he said he wanted to do dream interpretation with me. After talking to other doctors and google searching, I found dream interpretation is complete quackery; there's no science to it. Also the reason I went to see him had nothing at all to do with dreams.

Is it legal for medical provider to use something that's not based on science and not tell the patient?Where is the line drawn, for example surely a doctor can't prescribe medicine that hasn't been tested?

Comment: What sort of license did he have? That helps find the relevant rules of professional conduct.

Comment: @cpast Registered clinical social worker with Master's in social work

Comment: A social worker is not a medical provider and counseling is, in general, not really medicine or a science. Also, while dream interpretation may not intrinsically have science to it, talking to someone who listens to your concerns often has similar empirically demonstrated benefits without regard to the methods used or the qualifications of the listener. Getting advice from a volunteer grandma would be no more and no less effective and is consistently better than nothing. I don't even think it is fair to call it a placebo effect here. The therapy is in the listening, not in the advice given.

Comment: The question and the fact pattern are disjoint. The questions asked have little or nothing to do with the facts presented.